# multiselect spinner without a dialog

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a requirement where i have to implement a multiple - select spinner in android.

I want a normal spinner( which appears as a drop down) with check boxes for multiple -    select option. The selected options should appear as comma separated values after selection. 
I don't want a dialog to pop up when i select a spinner.I want spinner as a drop down.

I have gone through many example in the net, all examples pop up a dialog with check boxes or radio buttons for multiple select option. 
Can anyone please help me with this.
Is it possible to do?

Comment: do you try by changing the style of the spinner ?

Comment: http://v4all123.blogspot.in/2013/09/spinner-with-multiple-selection-in.html

Comment: https://github.com/wongk/MultiSelectSpinner

Comment: Changing the style will not work. sreekanthss

Comment: Segi - the examples in the links you have specified populates the options on a dialog . i don't want a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to inflate a [`Popup Window`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) at the position of your text.
In that popup window you could have checkboxes for multiple select option.